# Containerizing executables in Java

Tags: java, selenium, process, containers

I have a CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) application I am controlling with Selenium. Normally the application does not allow multiple instances of it to be running at the same time since it modifies directly its root files. I need to be able to run multiple instances (controlled by Selenium) though and some kind of containerization is therefore needed, correct? I've been looking into Docker containers, but as far as I understand, it doesn't really suit my needs as I need to be able to control the Selenium instances (or maybe other executables later on).

So, what should I do? Here's what I need:

- isolate processes
- the processes need to exist in some kind of virtual filesystem?
- probably be able to implement virtual network adapters
- be able to interact with the containerized process
- implemented in Java

How can I proceed?

Comment: What is a CEF application?

Comment: CEF = Chromium Embedded Framework. There is a complete Wikipedia article about it.

Comment: The processess need to interact. Could you specify how they interact? Do they use IPC, RMI, HTTP, sockets, shared memory, files on disk, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run your apps in docker, and run either selenium inside them independently ( so you have 1-1 relationship ) use Selenium Remote Webdriver and treat each docker instance as a remote machine (1 - many).

I don't think I can give you a concrete example because I have no idea what your application looks like nor it would be feasible to have it here, but these are basically the parts you are looking for:

- Run an app with docker
- Expose the apps to the host machine (your machine, where these dockers run)
- Use Selenium RemoteWebDriver to reach each one of the instances.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I kind of understand what you are suggesting, but I feel it does not work in this case - or at least how I understood it.

So, we are talking about an application here. I have a folder with all the application's files where the application runs from (remembering there can normally be only one instance of the app running). I then start the application and hook Selenium to it. To this point everything goes well. Now I just need to containerize this system, to run multiple instances in separate containers.

Is Docker really meant for this or where should I be looking?

Comment: That is EXACTLY what docker is for. You create an image where you specify all your files, programs, resources etc. etc, and then using docker you can create a new container for that image. You can think of each image as a separate machine (its own filesystem, network, etc)

Comment: Okay :) so, I create the image with Selenium (do I need to use the standalone version?) and the CEF application. Then, in Java code, how am I able to start the app and hook Selenium into it? Is the container completely headless or can I see all the applications running somehow?

Comment: So I'm assuming you currently have a Java program that has selenium inside and is able to control the CEF application right? Then when you create your image and start the container you just run that program. `java -cp something.jar params param params`

Comment: The containers need to be able to started from inside the Java during runtime because my Java program is not independently able to control the CEF app but requires other components of my Java application, if you understand? I need to containerize only the CEF application, not the Java application controlling it.

Comment: Perfect! It seems you have a clear path now to solve your problem and know better your own requirements. I would suggest split the problem in multiple small steps and solve them one at a time. For what I can see you first need to figure out A) how to create a docker image and create containers.  B) How to start containers from Java (or any other program for that matter e.g. ProcessBuilder)  C) How to connect your selenium program the "remote" VM's.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help :) I'll try to get this working. I am probably just overthinking this big time.